# tracial states on $C^*$ subalgebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$ algebra,$A=A_1\oplus A_2$.If $A$ has tracial state $\tau$,I want to show $A_1$ also has tracial state,say $\tau_1$.

My thought: let $\tau_1(a_1)=\tau(a_1,0)$,where $a_1 \in A_1$,but this construction does not assure that $\tau_1$ is nonzero.
Does there exist tracial state on $A_1$?

Comment: Given that a state is a linear funcitonal, as long as your C* algebra is not one-dimensional, it will probably send many things to $0$. Do you want your tracial state to be faithful?

Comment: The tracial state is not faithful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $A=B(H)\oplus \mathbb C$, with $\tau(T,\lambda)=\lambda$. Here $A_1$ has no tracial state.